# Arrays updates not seen in snapshot listener Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a simple document which looks like this :

[image]

I am attaching a snapshotListener to this collection.

the code is in `dart` but it's equivalent logic to any langage i have tried :

```
streamSubscription = query.snapshots().listen((event) {
      print("Listening event : " + event.docs.toString());
      for (DocumentChange documentChange in event.docChanges) {
        switch (documentChange.type) {
          case DocumentChangeType.added:
            addDoc(documentChange.doc);
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.modified:
            updateDoc(documentChange.doc);
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.removed:
            removeDoc(documentChange.doc);
            break;
        }
      }
    });
```

And the `updateDoc()` method is :

```
void updateDoc(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    TestObject test = TestObject.fromJson(data);
    print(test);
  }
```

Now if i change the `name` in the console, the `name` value is changed and we can see it in the `print(test)`.
However, if i remove the entry `secondtestvalue` from the array, the `updateDoc` is triggered but the `print(test)` still displays the value... Which means my array is not updated.

Is this a bug or i am missing something ?